# How do I see the exception traceback during debug in PyCharm?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

In PyCharm, whenever I step into an `except MyException:` scope, I want to see the traceback details of the exception.

for example:

```
try:
  raise_exc()
except MyException:
  handle_exc()  # <- current debug point
```

Can it be done?